# Validating an Armstrong number using Recursion in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have to check whether a number is an [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) or not, using a recursive method.

```
public class ArmStrong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isArm(407, 0, 0));
    }

    static boolean isArm(int n,int last,int sum) {
        if (n <= 0 ) {
            if (sum == n) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return isArm(n / 10, n % 10,sum + last * last * last);
    }
}
```

When I debug, in the last call of `isArm` when `n` is 4, the base statement is skipped.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ... and what is "the base satement"? For me, it enters the `if(...)` when `n` is `0`.

Comment: @neo-code The question is "a solution maybe"? This is not a question.

Comment: for me the debugger skips the if statement and gives errore

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/VsUlGQ).

Comment: @neo-code If you get an error, please post the error message.

Comment: @Turing85 yes I came here looking for solutions to my problem or if someone has better code. hope you understand.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. We do not do code review here (That is what [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for). And we do not rewrite your program. We answer specific questions. So please provide the necessary information. I recommend taking the [tour].

Comment: @ThomasBehr no sorry not a error but always prompts the false value.

Comment: @Turing85 thank you this is my first time using overflow

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into to the question, rather than leaving [comments](/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. See the [help] for more, especially "[ask]".

Comment: On an unrelated topic, see [using optional parameters in Java](/a/12994104/90527) for how to avoid having to pass initial values to `isArm`.

Comment: Using Stack Overflow as an interactive debugger is notoriously inefficient. Instead, find and learn to use whatever [debugger](/q/25385173/90527) your development suite provides. At that point, if you encounter a problem you can't solve you can then post a question about that specific issue. See "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)"

Comment: Probably you've meant that when `last` is `4` the `if`-statement in the *Base case* gets executed and the `sum` happens to be incorrect? Please [**fix the last sentence**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74414212/edit) of the question. It's important because Questions on StackOverflow are supposed to **provide value to Future Readers**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although *@rzwitserloot* has pointed at an issue which is rooted in the way you've designed the recursion, the problem is still **not** resolved.

Yes, the recursive calls go "one step ahead" the calculation of the `sum` of digits, which happens in the *Recursive case*, and the left-most digit of the given number doesn't contribute the `sum`, since `n` is zero and recursion hits the *Base case*. That's true, but it's not the only thing you need to fix.

Here's the definition of so-called [Narcissistic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) (aka Armstrong numbers):

> In number theory, a narcissistic number (also known as a pluperfect digital invariant (PPDI), an Armstrong number (after Michael F. Armstrong)or a plus perfect number) in a given number base b b is a number that is the sum of its own digits each **raised to the power of the number of digits**.

Therefore, a method with hard-coded power of `3` is capable to validate only three-digit Armstrong numbers. There are only few of them, for other valid Armstrong numbers it would produce an incorrect result.

So, before calculating the sum you need to know the numbers of digits there's no workaround. If you want to address the problem only by using Recursion, the numbers of digits can be also calculated recursively. If we take this route, the solution boils down to implementing two recursive methods.

That's how it might look like:

```
public static boolean isArm(int n) {
    return n == getSum(n, getDigitCount(n));
}

public static int getSum(int n, int power) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : (int) Math.pow(n % 10, power) + getSum(n / 10, power);
}

public static int getDigitCount(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : 1 + getDigitCount(n / 10);
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isArm(10));  // is not an Armstrong number
    System.out.println(isArm(21));  // is not an Armstrong number
    System.out.println(isArm(407)); // is an Armstrong number
    System.out.println(isArm(153)); // is an Armstrong number
    System.out.println(isArm(9));   // is an Armstrong number
}
```

*Output:*

```
false // 10
false // 21
true  // 407
true  // 153
true  // 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will instantly jump to the answer (`if (n <= 0)`) **before** applying the cube of the last digit.

For example, trivially, let's try `9`, which obviously isn't armstrong.

Your code will first check if 9 is 0 - it's not. So, we recurse, which will go with `self(0, 9, 0+0)`. The next run is supposed to then recurse once more, so that the `sum + last*last*last` can actually get some cubing done. But it'll never get there - n is 0, so, you jump into the `if`.

As your variable name kinda gives away `last` is referring to the digit that the previous run lopped off, and yet you aren't cubing it.

The solution is to simply get the cubing in *before* checking if `n` is null:

The first thing your method should do is

```
sum += last*last*last;
```

Then, the second problem shows up: This correctly calculates your sum to be 407, but you check this against `n`, which is, obviously, `0` - you are 'destroying' n as you go through. One trivial way to solve that is to pass the original n, unmolested, through, as a 4th parameter. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.